# C Help exercise

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, shared-libraries

"Write an algorithm that, given two ordered vectors of size N, prints all the elements that appear on both vectors, in an orderly fashion. The execution time of the program must be proportional to N in the worst case."

In this exercise, I was going to do an loop to check each number of array a[] and then use the binary search algorithm to check de array b[] and compare if it was equal to the array on a[].

But I don't know if on the worst case is proportional to N.

```
int main() {
    int a[6] = {2, 8, 15, 31, 46, 75};
    int b[6] = {1, 8, 17, 21, 31, 75};
    int i, tam = 6, key, res, c[6], k=0;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        key = a[i];
        res = binary_search(b, tam, key);
        if (res != -1) {
            c[k]=a[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int binary_search(int a[], int n, int key) {
    int low = 0, high = n - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (key < a[mid])high = mid - 1;
        else if (key > a[mid]) low = mid + 1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Try running through both vectors at the same time.

Comment: They're both ordered, so just iterate simultaneously. just iterate over `a`, and if `a[i] == b[i]`, print. If `a[i] < b[i]`, continue, if `a[i] > b[i]` move `b` to the next element and until `b[i]` is greater than or equal to `a[i]`. Pointer arithmetic is your friend here. Just make sure not to go out of bounds on `b`. That said, this is not a suitable SO question. There's no indication that you've tried anything yet. Some might say you're basically asking others to write the code you need for you

Comment: Way to give away the answer, guys.

Comment: If you are asking what's the best algorithm you should post at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead. If you need assistance with implementing a specific algorithm in C, you can ask here, but then please state exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know if on the worst case is proportional to N.

It's not. A binary search through an ordered list is O(log n). If you have to do that for all the elements in one of the arrays, you're looking at O(n log n).

When you're trying to solve a problem in O(n) time and your current solution is O(n log n), the part of your solution that's taking O(log n) is probably the problem.

Comment: I'm going to write a new code completly different from this one I have provided, so you can check if it obeys in the worst case O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a new code being this:

```
int main() {
    int a[6] = {2, 8, 15, 31, 46, 75};
    int b[6] = {1, 8, 17, 21, 31, 75};
    int i=0, j=0, N = 6, c[6], k = 0;

    while (i < N && j < N) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) {
            i++;
        } else if (a[i] > b[j]) {
            j++;
        } else {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think this one obeys the worst case O(n).
But still I want to thank you guys for the help!!

Comment: You forgot the prints.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define N 6

int main(void) {
    int a[N] = {2, 8, 15, 31, 46, 75};
    int b[N] = {1, 8, 17, 21, 31, 75};
    int i = 0, int j = 0, int n = 0;

    while (j + i < (N + N))
    {
        n = (b[j] - a[i]) & 0x80000000        // non null if b < a, else n = 0
        printf("%d\n", n ? b[j++] : a[i++]);  // access i if n=0 else if n=1 access j
        while (j == N && i != N)
            printf("%d\n", a[i++]);
        while (i == N && j != N)
            printf("%d\n", b[j++]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```